# Android -- Displaying background WebView as a Bitmap

Tags: android, webview, imageview

I would like to load a webview in the background and only display a bitmap of the page it loads.  I have a webview in my view hierarchy that has visibility set to "invisible" and an imageview that I wish to display a bitmap of the webview.

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#006330"));

webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(SiteAPI.URL, html, "text/html", "iso-8859-1", null);

webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight());

Bitmap b = webView.getDrawingCache(); 
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);          

if(b != null) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(b));
}
else {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The call to getDrawingCache() returns null everytime.  I've tried setContentView(webView) and the page displays fine.  I've made sure that isDrawingCacheEnabled() returns true, yet the bitmap is still null.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use [webView.capturePicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#capturePicture%28%29) method, but note that this will return a picture of the whole webpage, so you have to crop it to display just the part that you want.
2. Manually draw your webView in the Canvas object you want, using [webView.draw(Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29).